# How to update all colors in an editable PDF document?

Tags: python, pdf

I have a pdf that I can edit using Adobe Acrobat Pro.
For each color found in the document (solid filled rectangles, each pixel in an image, font color, ...) I need to update it to a new color. This new color is determined using a method that takes the old color (RGB or Hex) as input.

I can do this manually but to save time (100+ page doc) I'm looking for a solution to do this using Python.

Using Fitz I've been able to extract images and save the modified images, or cycle through the rectangles but I have not been able to find a way to update the pdf document and save a copy of it.

The only thing I need to change is the color, everything else needs to stays as is.

Is there a way to do this in python?

Edit Clarification:

I only need to update non-black and non-white objects. I only need to apply `f(colour) = newColour` for coloured objects. Note: `f(black) = black` and `f(white) = white` so I don't need to explicitly ignore these objects.

Comment: I'm lucky that I can ignore non-coloured objects (black or white: strings, rects, backgrounds, ...). I only need to apply `f(colour) = newColour` for objects have colours. Note: `f(black) = black` and `f(white) = white` so I don't need to explicitly ignore these objects.

Comment: Currently I'm working with fitz and I'm getting a pixmap of each page, but I'm experiencing a problem where the colours I'm getting in the pixMap are not identical to what's in the PDF.

Comment: Thank you. I've now decided to drop fitz and I'm just going to add a step to the process. I'm going to have to manually save the pdf as pngs using Adobe Acrobat Pro which does produce pngs with the correct colours. At that point I can easily code python to apply lambda to the pixels.

Comment: I agree, I was just hoping that fitz could convert to png with the same quality as Acrobat.